# pip3 failed to install ueberzug in fedora 36

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I have tried to install ueberzug an image preview python tool but unfortunately it is giving this error someone please help me how to resolve this issue as i don't know weather it is operating system(Fedora 36) problem or python issue.

Here is the command run

```
pip install ueberzug
```

Here is the output for the above command

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting ueberzug
  Downloading ueberzug-18.1.9.tar.gz (36 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: python-xlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from ueberzug) (0.31)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages (from ueberzug) (9.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: docopt in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from ueberzug) (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=18.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from ueberzug) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from python-xlib->ueberzug) (1.16.0)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for ueberzug, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: ueberzug
    Running setup.py install for ueberzug ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wsr8bot0/ueberzug_4bfe83741cb54dc5b20a8b59e18f636a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wsr8bot0/ueberzug_4bfe83741cb54dc5b20a8b59e18f636a/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-izxqd76_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/vmr/.local/include/python3.10/ueberzug
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-wsr8bot0/ueberzug_4bfe83741cb54dc5b20a8b59e18f636a/
    Complete output (53 lines):
    running install
    /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/action.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/batch.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/conversion.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/files.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/geometry.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/library.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/loading.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/pattern.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/process.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/query_windows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/scaling.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/terminal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/thread.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/tmux_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/ui.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    copying ueberzug/xutil.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug/lib
    copying ueberzug/lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug/lib
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug/lib/v0
    copying ueberzug/lib/v0/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug/lib/v0
    running egg_info
    writing ueberzug.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to ueberzug.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to ueberzug.egg-info/entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to ueberzug.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to ueberzug.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'ueberzug.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'ueberzug.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying ueberzug/lib/lib.sh -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/ueberzug/lib
    running build_ext
    building 'Xshm' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/Xshm
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-protector-strong -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-protector-strong -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-protector-strong -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c Xshm/Xshm.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/Xshm/Xshm.o
    Xshm/Xshm.c:5:10: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
        5 | #include <X11/Xlib.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wsr8bot0/ueberzug_4bfe83741cb54dc5b20a8b59e18f636a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wsr8bot0/ueberzug_4bfe83741cb54dc5b20a8b59e18f636a/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-izxqd76_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/vmr/.local/include/python3.10/ueberzug Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the gcc compiler cant find the X11 header files on your system, make sure you have the dev library installed

```
sudo dnf install libX11-devel.x86_64
```

You may also need the X11 extensions

```
sudo dnf install libXext-devel libXxf86vm-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has the same error like me when installed ueberzug.

Xshm/Xshm.c:5:10: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory

You need to install JPEG libraries.

sudo dnf install libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev python3-dev libxtst-dev

Answer (score 0):

Apart from above solutions.. u might need to add

```
sudo dnf install make automake gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel
```

this...

Answer (score 0):

You need the python dev libraries:

`sudo dnf install python3-devel`